# jQuery mobile automatic click/tab bug on next page in iOS7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm binding my tab events like this:

```
$('#submit').on("tap", function(){
    $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#page-2");
});
```

My Problem is that the tab event fires automatically on the same position on the next page.

So when I got 2 buttons on the same positions on two different pages and I click/tab on the first button, the view slides to the next page and the event fires on the second button too.

This is only happening in iOS7. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

(jQuery mobile version 1.4.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea if this will solve your problem or not, but you should probably be accepting an event parameter and preventing the default action if the click target is a button in a form or an anchor tag.  You might also want to prevent the event from bubbling up by using `stopPropagation`. Depending on the underlying element you may actually be seeing the effect of the default action for that element or getting a full page refresh.  That might have the appearance of the other action being invoked.

```
$('#submit').on("tap", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // and also maybe prevent the event from bubbling up

    $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#page-2");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate! That solved my problem. It seems that jQuery mobile had the the same problem in version 1.0.
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1331